# Write CSV of each dataframe in a list

Tags: r, list, csv

I need to save individual .csv files for each dataframe in a large list

```
    file <- split(x, x$Advertiser)
```

My attempt is as follows...

```
    for(i in file){
          write.csv(file[[i]],paste(names(file)[i]))
    }
```

However, I receive the following error, which seems to indicate you can't apply write.csv to a list.

```
Error in file[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Is there a proper method for achieving this?

Comment: your code has a serious error, even writing for loop was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this works out for you:

```
lapply(seq_along(myFile), function(i) {
    write.csv(myFile[[i]],
              file = paste0(names(myFile[i]), ".csv"),row.names = FALSE)
})
```